# Galen Framework for Windows 7

Tags: galen

I'm pretty novice to galen framework, and the guy (developer) of it explains everything indistinctly so I can't understand anything. I'm a Windows(7) man, so where do I create the file so called home-spec? Is it notepad++? Or Office Word file? And how I integrate it with Selenium? Thanks for response in advance.

Comment: you can integrate Galen with Selenium

Comment: @hypery2k Thanks a lot, but I've already implemented my own UI framework for verifying page layout..

Answer (score 1):

galen framework is used to test UI..... windows or mac doesn't matter.
consider Galen as just set of commands that crosscheck UI as per your specifications.
1st **install** galen on ur system..
http://mindengine.net/post/2014-01-08-configuring-galen-framework-for-windows/#.VhQVd7SqpHw

then **download** selenium jar..
 do this first.. then will guide u further.

Comment: you don't need to download selenium separately

Comment: then how will u use Galen without Selenium ??

Comment: selenium is bundled within the Galen JAR

Answer (score 1):

you can install galen via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/galenframework-cli) and you can find an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/hypery2k/galen_samples/tree/master/javascript). There you also find a basic folder structure to start with

Answer (score 0):

use npm:

1) `npm install -g galenframework-cli`
2) then `galen config`
3) adjust the config to match your drivers etc
4) then run galen home-spec

- but seriously if you asking about whether to create the file in notepad++ or word, spend at least a night learning about IDEs.